# Customizer List of Items

Tags: theme-customizer, api

I am working with Customizer api
for text for example

```
  $wp_customize->add_setting('basic-author-callout-text', array(
            'default' => '',
            'sanitize_callback' => array( $this, 'sanitize_custom_text' )
        ));
        $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Control($wp_customize, 'basic-author-callout-control', array(
            'label' => 'About Author',
            'section' => 'basic-author-callout-section',
            'settings' => 'basic-author-callout-text',
            'type' => 'textarea'
        )));
```

I want to add a list of items , do anyone has an idea about this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, could you please clarify what it is you would like? Would you like a bunch of input fields to make a list on the site?

Comment: List :
-item1 
-item2....